# javaFX: a custom control(made with scene builder) contain a buttom with an onAction

Tags: javafx, controls, action

javaFX: a custom control(made with scene builder) contain a buttom with an onAction(and other components). How can i implement the method when i use the controll in another screen ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually wrap the event with a custom event, e.g. "onMyCustomAction".

Your control needs a custom eventHandler property and fire the event:

```
public class MyCustomControl extends ... {


private final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<MyCustomActionEvent>> onMyCustomAction = new ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<MyCustomActionEvent>>() {
    @Override
    protected void invalidated() {
        setEventHandler(MyCustomActionEvent.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION, get());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return MyCustomControl.this;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "onMyCustomAction";
    }
};

...

public MyCustomControl () {
    <load fx:root based FXML>
}

...

public final EventHandler<MyCustomActionEvent> getOnMyCustomAction() {
    return onMyCustomActionProperty().get();
}

public final void setOnMyCustomAction(EventHandler<MyCustomActionEvent> onMyCustomAction) {
    onMyCustomActionProperty().set(onMyCustomAction);
}

public ObjectProperty<EventHandler<MyCustomActionEvent>> onMyCustomActionProperty() {
    return onMyCustomAction;
}

...

@FXML
private void handleMyButtonOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    fireEvent(new MyCustomActionEvent(<someData>);
}
```

And a custom Event:

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventType;


public class MyCustomActionEvent extends Event {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = <some id>;
    public static final EventType<MyCustomActionEvent> MY_CUSTOM_ACTION = new EventType<>("MY_CUSTOM_ACTION");
    private final Foo foo;

    public MyCustomActionEvent(Foo foo) {
        super(MY_CUSTOM_ACTION);
        this.foo = foo;
    }


    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

The client code can then register an EventHandler for "onMyCustomAction" (this works even via FXML like with the standard controls):

```
myCustomControl.setOnMyCustomAction(event -> doSomething(event.getFoo()));

...

private void doSomething(Foo foo) {
...
}
```

Or with FXML:

```
<MyCustomControl onMyCustomAction="#doSomething" />
```

And provide a method:

```
@FXML
private void doSomething(MyCustomActionEvent event) {
...
}
```

**Update 15.09.2016**

I've created a utility class [SimpleEventHandlerProperty](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/event/SimpleEventHandlerProperty.html) to simplify custom event handler properties:

```
private final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<SomeEvent>> onMyCustomAction = new SimpleEventHandlerProperty<>(this,
            "onMyCustomAction ", MyCustomActionEvent.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION, this::setEventHandler);
```

Using this utility class, the anonymous class for onMyCustomAction is not needed anymore.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: sorry but i always are not able to solve the question

Comment: a lot of thanks to everybody now i'm run every things and i can go to ski . ciao

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a callback that can be implemented. 
Example:

```
public class myControl {
    private Button button;
    private Callback<Void, Void> buttonCallback;
    public myControl() {
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if(getButtonCallback() !=  null){
                    getButtonCallback().call(null);
                }

            }
        });


    }
    public Callback<Void, Void> getButtonCallback() {
        return buttonCallback;
    }
    public void setButtonCallback(Callback<Void, Void> buttonCallback) {
        this.buttonCallback = buttonCallback;
    }

}
```

Now you can provide different implementations of the callback using the setter.

Comment: sorry but i always are not able to solve the question